# External Javascript running after local Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a PHP page with some Javascript/Jquery code inside it.

I have something like this:

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {

    my_external_function();

    other code here...
}
```

but my_external_function (which is included in an external js file) seems to run AFTER the local code. In fact, the "return false" included in my_external_function is ignored and it continues to execute the other local code.

What did I mistake?

Please notice that if I try to copy the content of my_external_function inside the local page, everything works correctly.

Any suggestion is appreciated, thank you!

Just to clarify, even if I empty the external function and I leave one line (the RETURN FALSE instruction), this is ignored, and the PHP page continues to run the other code of the click event.

To make it simple, this works (the execution is stopped correctly):

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {

    return false;

    other code here...
}
```

This doesn't work (the submit is performed):

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {

    my_external_function();

    other code here...
}
```

the content of external js file now is:

```
function my_external_function() {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Where is the code for my_external_function, seems like it is async in nature

Comment: We can't really know without an actual example of the problem.  Currently your click handler has exactly one line if code in it: `my_external_function();`.  That line of code is guaranteed to be the first and only thing that function does.  Pro tip: When you claim that the language framework itself is fundamentally broken but aren't able to provide an example to demonstrate it, you're *probably* mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Simply returning false from an inner function does not halt execution of the calling function.  This code:

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {
    my_external_function();
    // other code here...
}

function my_external_function() {
    return false;
}
```

is equivalent to this:

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {
    false;   
    // other code here... (will run)
}
```

It is *not* equivalent to this:

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {
    return false;  
    // other code here... (unreachable)
}
```

(Note that in this second example,   `return true` would also halt execution of the click handler; once a function returns, that function is done.  Many code editors will flag it as an error if you have unreachable code after a `return` statement.)

If you want that "other code here" to never run at all, you could use `return my_external_function()`.   If you want it to run conditionally on whether `my_external_function()` returns true or false, you'd do

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {
    if (my_external_function()) {
      // other code here
      return true; // if necessary
    } else {
      return false; // if necessary
    }
})
```

Comment: You're right, it was a simple problem indeed. I used the last option to run the other code conditionally. Thank you very much.